# How do I decode a Private key generated with Nethereum (converted AsBytes().ToHex())?

Tags: c#, blockchain

I created PrivateKeys with Nethereum library like this:

```
var ecKey = Nethereum.Signer.EthECKey.GenerateKey();
var privateKey = ecKey.GetPrivateKeyAsBytes().ToHex();
```

But i can't get the privateKey decoded.

I tried it this way and also with the HextoByteArray Method from Nethereum, but both didn't work.

```
strAccKey = "40bbe961e04f7e83596d1b559b9ec7022b3eac8512077938a95dfba7657a8e90";
string result = strAccKey.HexToUTF8String();
txtPrivKey.Text = result;
```

Comment: Convert it from "hex string" back to bytes, not to a new string. Find the opposite of `.ToHex`.

Comment: I also tried it this way, but also didn't work....
strAccKey = "40bbe961e04f7e83596d1b559b9ec7022b3eac8512077938a95dfba7657a8e90";
            byte[] bytes = strAccKey.HexToByteArray();
            string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

            txtPrivKey.Text = result;

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? How do you judge the outcome, whether it is correct or not? Is the private key **as bytes** supposed to be readable text?

Comment: the outcome is a line of signs not recognizeable.
the decoded privatekey should be readable

Comment: If you took an array of bytes, converted it to hex, then back to an array of bytes, then converted the final array of bytes to a string through UTF8 decoding, and the text is not readable, it was not readable to start with.

Comment: okay, so how can I get the array of bytes to a private key string?

Comment: How/where do you want to use the "private key **string**"? Which format does that thing expect?

Comment: the "private key" is a string of 64 hex characters

Comment: Well, don't you already have that then, in `strAccKey`?